# Reversing names in file input and output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a problem in an online MOOC on intro to python programming. I am stuck on how to complete the below problem. Could you please offer some guidance?

The problem is below:
You've been sent a list of names. Unfortunately, the names come in two different formats:

First Middle Last
Last, First Middle

You want the entire list to be the same. For this problem, we'll say you want the entire list to be First Middle Last.

Write a function called name_fixer. name_fixer should have two parameters: an output filename (the first parameter) and the input filename (the second parameter). You may assume that every line will match one of the two formats above: either First Middle
Last or Last, First Middle.

name_fixer should write to the output file the names all
structured as First Middle Last. If the name was already structured
as First Middle Last, it should remain unchanged. If it was
structured as Last, First Middle, then Last should be moved
to the end after a space and the comma removed.

The names should appear in the same order as the original file.

For example, if the input file contained the following lines:
David Andrew Joyner
Hart, Melissa Joan
Cyrus, Billy Ray

...then the output file should contain these lines:
David Andrew Joyner
Melissa Joan Hart
Billy Ray Cyrus

Add your code here!
My code:

```
def name_fixer(output_filename, input_filename):
file = open(filename, 'r')
for char in string:
if char == ',':
string.remove(',')
value = string.reverse()
file.close()
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the data you are working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### input_file.txt

```
David Andrew Joyner 
Hart, Melissa Joan
Cyrus, Billy Ray
Kevin Pietersen
Rowling, Johanne Kimberley
```

### CODE

```
def name_fixer(input_file, output_file):
    with open(input_file, "r") as f, open(output_file, "w+") as g:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if ',' in line:
                line = ' '.join(line.split(',')[::-1]).strip()
            g.write(f"{line}\n")

myinputfile = "input_file.txt"
myoutputfile = "output_file.txt"
name_fixer(myinputfile, myoutputfile)
```

### output_file.txt

```
David Andrew Joyner
Melissa Joan Hart
Billy Ray Cyrus
Kevin Pietersen
Johanne Kimberley Rowling
```